# CoreData Unique: Decide update or create

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I'm using CoreData in my project and I'm thinking about unique fields and creating objects or updating them if they are already existing.

UseCase:

- Get JSON from Server
- Map JSON to Object
- Save to CoreData

What I want to do is:

- Get JSON from Server
- Map JSON to Object
- Does the object already exists (Unique field is unique identifier for object)
- If YES

  - Get object
  - Update fields
- If NO

  - Create object
- Save to CoreData

Isn't that a lot overhead for the solution? So every time I get an object I have to check the CoreData. Is there something that can do this handeled by CoreData internally?

Comment: I wouldn't say that uses a lot of memory, in fact it is a method I have used recently in a production application.

Comment: Have a look at ["Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the Core Data Programming Guide!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) it has built in maps from JSON to core data and will keep unique items unique.